# Button that returns dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, button, jupyter

I have a Jupyter Notebook that contains a button, some dropdowns, and a dataframe. Essentially, selections are made in a dropdown, and after clicking the button, a dataframe containing values selected in the dropdowns is produced.

My dropdowns work perfectly. However, my button does not return the dataframe.

Here is my code for the button:

```
 def on_button_clicked(b):
    # some code that creates from dropdown selections, x. 

    df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=index,columns=['Pilot', 'Baseline', 'Change'])
    return(df)


 button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
 display(button)
```

Why won't the dataframe simply return? I have tried using `display(df)` before, but everytime the button is clicked, a dataframe is printed everytime.

I simply want the dataframe to change based on user selection when the button is clicked. Any tips on how to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Using `with out:` the output of the button can dynamically change, i.e. the dataframe changes based on user selection.

In my case, I used:

```
out = widgets.Output()

...


def on_button_clicked(b):
   # some code that creates from dropdown selections, x. 

   df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=index,columns=['Pilot', 'Baseline', 'Change'])
   with out:
       clear_output(True)
       display(df)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

with out:
    display(df)

out
```